# $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1 − a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n =1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $0
< a_n
<
1$, then
$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1 − a_n)$  converges if and only if $\sum_{n =1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Any help would be appreciated. I tried to use $\frac{x}{x-1} \le \ln(1-x) \le -x$ for all $x<1$, but no luck.

Comment: Take the logarithm of the left side and use the Taylor series for $\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: For small $x$, $\log(1-x) \approx -x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove two directions separately:  Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $T_n = \prod_{k=1}^n (1-a_k)$.
($\Leftarrow$) As suggested by the inequality that you mentioned
\begin{align}
T_n = \prod_{k=1}^n (1-a_k) &= \prod_{k=1}^n e^{\ln(1-a_k)} \\
&=e^{\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(1-a_k)} \\
&\le e^{-\sum_{k=1}^na_k} = e^{-S_n}.
\end{align}
($\Rightarrow$) Conversely, assume that $S_n$ diverges. It is clear that $a_n\to 0$, otherwise $T_n$ would diverge(By Cauchy criterion for infinite products). Let $K_n = \prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k)$.
$$T_nK_n = \prod_{k=1}^n (1-a_k^2)< 1.$$ Hence $T_n<1/K_n\to 0$ since $K_n>S_n\to \infty$. It implies that $T_n$ diverges to $0$ which is a contradiction.